# Как перенаправить запрос в интернет через локальную сеть?

Tags: java, javafx, webview

Доброго время суток, у меня есть следующая специфическая проблема.
Есть программа написанная на java, которая работает на двух компьютерах соединенных в одну сеть. Один компьютер имеет доступ в интернет, а другой нет. Программы общаются между собой с помощью JGroup. На компьютере без интернета есть элемент WebView (javaFX). Как сделать так, что бы этот элемент смог выгрузить и отобразить например google.com?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вам действительно нужно заново изобретать прокси с браузером? Или у вас какая-то специфическая задача?

Comment: Сделать прокси внутри моей программы решило бы задачу, но в моем случае будет достаточно каким то образом сохранить веб страницу со всеми ресурсами (картинки, стили скрипты) на компьютере с интернетом и передав все это на другой открыть нужный сайт из сохраненных данных. Изначально предполагается что сайт будет загружен один раз и дальше не будет обновляться.